# Manhua about a guy being reincarnated with an invincible domain system

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, cultivation

I read this manhua a few weeks ago and had it bookmarked, but one of my friends used my laptop and did something. I remember it being about this guy who was reincarnated as some beggar, I think in a temple, and he gets a system that makes him invincible within a certain range.

I read it recently so I will give the details I remember. First he fights some enemy and punches him from within his domain, which causes a fist-shaped hole that pierces to the upper domain. Some kind of sword falls down, attracting other cultivators. Then a girl goes to find the treasure and is being chased by some evil sect members. She becomes his disciple.

Comment: What is a domain system? Is that a manhua term?

Comment: It's a [cultivation](https://xian-ni.fandom.com/wiki/Cultivation) term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It's called *'Invincible at the Start'*

> *“Ding, the host has opened the invincible field! As long as the host is invincible in the field…!”* As a nerd, Chen Changan travels through the fantasy world, facing countless monsters and ghosts from the outside world, Chen Changan decided not to leave his invincible field before becoming immortal. When he is bored, he occasionally raises a few cute and sweet apprentices, and accidentally cultivated them to become leaders in the spiritual world, which turned the world upside down.
>
> [image]

Comment: I've added in a blurb and the cover image. I'm genuinely struggling to find a legit source to link to.

Comment: @Valorum is mangaupdates not considered acceptable?

Comment: @qazmlpok: We're not allowed to link to any site that provides pirated materials, including unofficial "scanlations". But Mangaupdates looks pretty decent.

Comment: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: @qazmlpok - MangaUpdates is basically an aggregator of illegal links. They don't host the stuff themselves, but their sole purpose for existence is to link to illegal sources. So no, I wouldn't think it was acceptable.

Comment: @Valorum: Ah. I hadn't seen the illegal links. Clicking around just seemed to lead to further informational pages. I do see now that, if you go to a translation group's page, it includes a link to their page, if not to the individual chapters translated.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find better reference (and a legal site to link), but maybe *Lan Ke Qi Yuan*?

[image: Front cover of Lan Ke Qi Yuan]

> Leaves fell on the chess game by the side of Rotten Ke, and the old trees played against each other due to the uninteresting son of Tian Yuan, and then looked back on the vast mountains and seas… When he woke up, Ji Yuan became a half-blind beggar in a dilapidated mountain temple. The sword, the sacred stick and one mouth are the foundation for Ji Yuan to settle down in this terrible world.

[Lan Ke Qi Yuan](https://manhwatop.com/manga/lan-ke-qi-yuan/)

Comment: Thanks, I have read this before but it's not the one I'm looking for sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be *[Return of Mount Hua Sect](https://www.readlightnovel.me/return-of-mount-hua-sect)*?

> The 13th disciple of the Great Mount Hua Sect. One of the Greatest Third-Generation Swordsmen. The Plum Blossom Sword Master, Chungmyung.
>
> After slicing the head of the peerless Heavenly Demon, who threw the world into chaos, he slept an eternal sleep on the peak of the Hundred Thousand Great Mountains. Jumping over a hundred years, he comes back in the body of a child.

The manhua, like the original novel, had the swordsman reincarnate as a beggar.

Comment: no it's definitely not. thanks for trying though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier, but in what ways does it  not match up?